# iOS/xcode/objective-c: create session variable for reachability

Tags: ios, xcode, reachability

I do a test in app delegate using the reachability class to see if there is an Internet connection.  I put this in app delegate since I need to check Internet access in many parts of the app at many points and thought app delegate is always running in background..

I created a boolean variable hasInternet in app delegate but can't seem to access it elsewhere.  The following in another class throws error:

```
     if (hasInternet) {
//do something
        }
```

Is this the right approach to keeping track of reachability or how can I set a variable that can be checked throughout the entire app.

Comment: You haven't put nearly enough info... Please post the method you're using in your app delegate to set `hasInternet`. And is `hasInternet` a public variable?

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid option, but to use this variable you have to declare it as a *property* (possibly only read-only in .h, and read-write in .m). You can then access it in other classes with

```
((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).hasInternet
```

<sub>(where `AppDelegate` is the actual name of your app delegate class)</sub>